# Postgresql: how to get all queries to a tables or database for a current user?

Tags: postgresql

I need to get all queries to a tables for current user in Postgresql, how to do that? I need it for an audit. 
 I installed pgbadger but it was not show queries its just showing a count of some queries,for example, user1 have made 3 queries to a table1, but i need to get something like this: 
*“user1 made select * from table1 at %timestamp%; user1 made alter table …* “ and etc. 
 could someone help?

Answer (score 0):

i used pgbadger and try this [solution](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgstatstatements.html) from postgres off docs

in-build tool for monitor user activity

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).